# jQuery array keep returning [object Object]

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am creating a jQuery array but my code keeps returning [object Object], 3 times.

Here is my code:

```
var idArray = [];
$('.taskPHP').each(function() {
  var idStr = { 
    'taskPHPid': $(this).attr('id'), 
    'taskValue': $(this).val() 
  }
  idArray.push(idStr);
});

alert(idArray);
```

EDIT:
Just call me stupid...i knew i couldn't alert an array. err...to many beers and programming don't mix.

I will give u credit as soon as I can. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon from after the closing-brace `}`.

Comment: @DavidThomas The missing semicolon shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: @William, that's why I left it as a comment (sloppy syntax, even while still 'correct,' bothers me is all). =)

Comment: javascript arrays are objects too. which means alerting them should yield "object". functions are objects too and they yield "object" too when alerted except internal functions which yield "function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems fine, try `console.log` and see what it outputs, or `alert(JSON.stringify(idArray))`

Answer (score 1):

The default "to string" for an `Object` is "[object Object]".

This is what the `Array.toString` implementation is calling for all of the elements it contains. (Array has a standard "pretty" string representation, but only in a shallow fashion.)

Stringify it to JSON first (i.e. `JSON.stringify`) or use a *smart* `console.log` (i.e. like Chrome's) that doesn't just call `[[ToString]]` on the result ..

Answer (score 0):

You can't view Objects in an `alert()` window.

If you want to see the contents of the Object, use:

```
console.log(idArray); // doesn't work in IE of course
```